# How can I get a relative path text file to be sent as an email attachment in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, email, text, attachment, relative-path

Hello Stack overflow community, for a security class, I'm trying to replicate a "bad" usb being plugged in and then sending a generated text file to a recipient via outlook.

I will say I am a PowerShell novice by all means so this may be something simple that I just don't understand.

I cannot get the relative path for $var1 to work.

When I use an absolute path to the generated file it sends the attachment fine.

I'm trying to use the `Get-ChildItem e:\ -filter "*.txt"` to populate this variable dynamically, but when it gets to the `.Attchments.Add($var1)` it breaks with `Error while invoking Add. Could not find member.`

Meanwhile, the .Count function on it does return a 1 signifying that the file is there.

I could not find a good indication of what this error means. Googling the error results in Microsoft documentation and nothing as it relates to programming in Powershell. I've tried messing with `'`'s around the Get-ChildItem statement and various other syntactical tweaks. I haven't found a good alternative to the way we've decided to send the email thus far. Securing SMTP for this isn't practical as it wouldn't fit the scenario.

```
New-Item -Path E:\ -Name "DynamicNameOfPC" -ItemType "file" -Value "Test"
(Get-ChildItem e:\ -filter "*.txt").Count

$var1 = Get-ChildItem e:\ -filter "*.txt"


$OL = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application

Start-Sleep 5
#Create Item
$mItem = $OL.CreateItem("olMailItem")

$mItem.To = "Test@test.com"
$mItem.Subject = "Testing Script"
$mItem.Body = "Testing"
$mItem.Attachments.Add($var1)
$mItem.Send()
```

`

Comment: Relative path? Relative to what? And how would that help? Sounds like a red-herring. `Get-ChildItem` doesn't return pathnames as strings, it returns FileInfo objects, that's probably what breaks add(). If absolute paths work (and they should) then `$var1.FullName` should work.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the .FullName function. That worked as well as the rigged way that I did it in the self-answer. .FullName is obviously a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Through analysis with a random user on a Discord, We were able to realize the Get-ChildItem was getting the file name but not the full path.

Adding a variable with the path of E:\ before `$var1` got it working perfectly.

Comment: I recommend you read and understand [TessellatingHeckler's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877511/how-can-i-get-a-relative-path-text-file-to-be-sent-as-an-email-attachment-in-pow#comment76734981_44877511). [`Get-ChildItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) returns [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DirectoryInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), which include full path as property `Fullname`.